# How to add a number to a duplicated string?

Tags: php, duplicates

I have a string like this:
$str = 'car, dog, house, dog, dog, house, dish';

How can I have a output like this:

```
dog #1
dog #2
dog #3
car
house #1
house #2
dish
```

Because I want to make the duplicated Strings to be a unique String by adding a number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please post your attempts too.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `str_word_count` and `array_count_values` functions:

```
$str = 'car, dog, house, dog, dog, house, dish';
$counts = array_count_values(str_word_count($str, 1));

foreach ($counts as $name => $c) {
    if ($c == 1) {
        echo $name . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $c; $i++) echo $name . ' #'. $i . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
car
dog #1
dog #2
dog #3
house #1
house #2
dish
```